# object.style.order not updating more than once

Tags: javascript, css, dom, styles

When setting an object's flexbox order style with js using object.style.order, it works without a problem the first time. When I try to do so again by calling the same method, it does not work. The code is as follows

```
send_message = function(message, jid) {
  node = document.createElement("div")
  node.classList.add("chat", "chat_outgoing", "sending")
  node.innerText = message
  var order = Date.now() - 1
  document.getElementById(jid).style.order = 0 - Date.now()
  request({
    method: "post",
    body: {
      message: message,
      peer_jid: jid
    },
    json: true,
    url: `${flask}/send`
  }).on("response", function(response) {
    node.classList.remove("sending")
    node.classList.add("delivered")
  })
  threads[jid].appendChild(node)
  document.getElementById("thread").innerHTML = threads[jid].innerHTML
  update_chat_scroll()
}
```

Trying it a little bit differently also does not work

```
  document.getElementById(jid).style.order = 0 - Date.now()
```

However when I try to do the same thing in the developer console, it works the way I'd expect it to. Is there some issue with my calling of Date.now() that's causing it not to return a value, or am I not using .style.order correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?